# generate propriet non repeating ids

Tags: javascript, html, tags

On my site a user can generate as many select fields as he needs. Each one is placed into li tag. When each tag is added, page count how many tags of that type are on the page and that number plus always repeating string is given as an id of that element. Problem occurs when user delete some of these tags. Page will then start giving already existing ids. What is the best way to generate ids for this kind of page?

example:

```
<li id="0_li_text">
<li id="1_li_text"> <-- delete
<li id="2_li_text">

<li id="0_li_text">
<li id="2_li_text">
<li id="2_li_text"> <-- this one will be generated
```

Comment: it based on what do you need from li elements? Maybe you need nothing, but storing ids for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may generate an unique ID, by creating a variable, and increments on each li added.

Comment: I was originally going to suggest messing around with CSS classes and formatted IDs, but this seems like a much better way to do this. +1. just remember to persist the variable when the tags are persisting as well, and reset it when the tags are reset.

Comment: This works. I though that I would need to use some store functions etc.